# .CommandText in an ODBC query (EXCEL VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, odbc

I have successfully used this function to access a database for a couple of years now. The Var string always contains a valid SQL that is dynamically built depending on the data of the day.

```
Function Get_Query_Results(Rng As Range, Location As String, var As String, UID As String, PWD As String) As Long
    Rng.Select
    On Error GoTo TroubleWithDatabase
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:="ODBC;DSN=XDR223;UID=" & UID & ";PWD=" & PWD & ";", Destination:=Rng).QueryTable
        .CommandText = var
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Get_Query_Results = LastInCol(Columns(Location)) - 1
    Exit Function
TroubleWithDatabase:
    Get_Query_Results = 0
End Function
```

The LastInCol function sets the value of the function to the number of records retrieved. If there's an error, the value of the function is set to 0.

Today I traced a problem with the line

```
    .CommandText = var
```

When it attempts to execute that line, an error is trapped and then jumps to TroubleWithDatabase and exits.

As I've said, this has never failed me until today. Today, var exceeded 32767 characters in length. It is 33582 characters in length. I suspecting that .CommandText can't take more than 32767 characters, which I find strange. Can anybody confirm?

Better yet, can anybody see any errors at all with the function?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you disable the error handler, what's the text of the error?

Comment: That is the weird thing. It exits the function right after it goes over the .CommanText instruction without producing an error. Execution does not stop, but since the query really didn't produce data, the code fails elsewhere. Only with the debugger was I able to pinpoint the root cause of the problem to that very instruction. I am using Excel 2007.

Comment: Clarifying my above comment: The function is still exited after .CommandText after disabling the error when the Var variable is 33582 characters in length.

Comment: I see other references online to a ~32k character limit, but no references to a work-around.  Can you split your query into multiple pieces and append each set of results?  Without seeing your SQL it's difficult to make suggestions.

Comment: It is confirmed.  .CommandText does not take strings larger than 32767.  I rewrote the query using aliasing to save space on its size and got it to run a few more iterations until it grew to a size exceeding 32767.  Then it failed again.

Comment: Are you running a large `where blah in(...)`-type query ?

Comment: Yes.  The where parts are what makes the query so large.